# AT Commands PHP

Tags: php, sms, gsm, at-command

I want to send messages from php by using a GSM modem. I have configured the modem and tested it using Hyperterminal. Now I want to execute AT commands using php. Is there any open source library available for that, or some other solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since my php application is hosted on an Apache webserver, I used python, pyserial and mod_wsgi to send the SMS, thanks for all the help.

Comment: That's how I solved the problem, that's surely not answer to question because it was "Sending SMS using php."

Answer (score -2):

I haven't used this myself but someone i know used it a while ago.

http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/