# GSM modem SMS sending error: unable to setup com port

Tags: php, xampp, sms, gsm

i was using this code ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632966/11144183
and i thought the problem was solve but this thing pop up

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to setup COM port,

> check it is correct' in C:\xammp\htdocs\gnokii\send.php:56 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xammp\htdocs\gnokii\send.php(18): gsm_send_sms->init() #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xammp\htdocs\gnokii\send.php on line 56

i've used the PORT COM given on the modem and also the baudrate but it always showing this error hope you can help me thanks in advance